# Is the set that contains the empty set {∅} also a subset of all sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think it isn't; although $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, $\{\emptyset\}$ is only a subset of a set $A$ if $A$ contains the element $\emptyset$. So if $A = \{\emptyset\}$, then both $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are subsets of A, but if we have a set $B$ where $B = \{0, 1\}$ then only $\emptyset$ is a subset of it.

If my reasoning is true, then if there was a set $C$ where $C = \{\emptyset, 0, 1\}$, would $\{\emptyset\}$ then be a subset of $C$?

Moreover, is this a valid set (i.e. can you have the empty set as an element of a set that contains other elements)?

Comment: Given $C = \{ \emptyset, 0,1\}$ would you say $\{1\} \subset C$? Apply the reasoning for this answer to your question of '$\{ \emptyset\} \subset C $?'.

Comment: What you've posited is correct. It is true that $\varnothing$ is a subset of any set, but $\{\varnothing\}$ is only a subset of sets containing $\varnothing$. And such sets can exist. For example, we say that the power set of a set $A$, denoted $P(A)$, is the set of all subsets of $A$. Since $\varnothing$ is a subset of $A$, it is an element of $P(A)$. Furthermore, if $A$ is nonempty, then $P(A)$ will have elements other than $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is right. If $A=\{ \emptyset \}$ then both $\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}$ will be subsets of $A$.

Applying the same reasoning, if $C=\{ \emptyset, 0,1 \}$ as @oliverjones states we can say $\{1\} \subset C$ because we have a $1$ inside $C$ in its definition (the same way there it’s an $\emptyset$ inside $A$ in its definition). With this in mind it’s easy to see that in fact $\{\emptyset\} \subset C$ and it’s a valid set.

Answer (score 3):

Not only can you have the empty set as a member of other sets, but the classical way of building the natural numbers out of set theory does nothing but nest empty sets inside other sets.  We do that by defining $0=\emptyset$,  then $1=\{0\}$,   and in general,  $n=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.   Writing these out long form gets you tons of empty sets!

Comment: I was just about to remark on this construction of $\mathbb{N}$ ,+1

Comment: In 9th grade,Exercise 4 was to show 2+2=4, it took me 3/4 of a page...

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have confusion between begin  element and begin a subset. Consider, the following example $$A=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$$ Now, $\emptyset\in A$ and $\{\emptyset\}\in A$. But, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset A.$ I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, simply use the *definition* of "subsets".

> $A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if "every element of $A$ is an element of $B$".

So your question is equivalent to

> is $\emptyset$ **an element** of an arbitrary set?

Of course not: the empty set is a subset of any set, but it is not necessarily an *element* of a set. The set $\{1\}$ is such an example.